# Guidelines for a Password Checker

Tags: java

I am working on a password checker and I need some help. If possible I need to make the checker as "realistic" as possible. Meaning it needs to actually register the password and have dialogue. I managed to get some guidelines down: Password needs to be 8-12 Characters, 1 number, 1 special character, and a Capital letter. Im having trouble with storing the password into a database and not allowing two of the same character in consecutive order(Ex. aa)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class passworChk{

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int min =8;
int max=12;
int digit=0;
int special=0;
int upCount=0;
int loCount=0;
int count=0;
String password;
String decision;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Your Password: ");
    password = scan.nextLine();
    //Sees if the Password is okay
if(count <= 0){
    System.out.println("No password registered. would you like to register a      new password? Enter yes or no.");
    decision = scan.nextLine();
if(decision.length() == 3){
    System.out.println("Enter Your Password: ");
    password = scan.nextLine();
    count++;
}
else if(decision.length() == 2){
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
    System.exit(0);
}
}
if(count >= 0){ 
if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max){
    for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        //This code goes through the 'password' String and registers it   through counts.
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
            upCount++;
        }
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
            loCount++;
        }
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            digit++;
        }
        if(password.contains("&") || password.contains("!") ||  password.contains("@") || password.contains("#") || password.contains("$") || password.contains("*") || password.contains("%") || password.contains("?")){
            special++;
        }
    }//If all the counts are in the correct ranges, the password is acceptable.
    if(special>=1&&loCount>=1&&upCount>=1&&digit>=1){
        System.out.println("Your Password is acceptable.");
    }

}

if(password.length()<min){

    for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
            loCount++;
        }
        }

    if(loCount>0){
        System.out.println("Your Password must be at least "+min+" characters.");
        System.out.println(" You need at least one upper case chracter,");
        System.out.println(" You need at least one digit.");
        System.out.println(" You need at least one special chracter.");



}
}
else if(password.length()<min&&upCount>1){
    for(int i =0;i<password.length();i++){
    char c =password.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c)){
        loCount++;
    }
     if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
        upCount++;
    }
    }
    if(loCount>0&&upCount>0){
    System.out.println(" Password must be at least "+min+" chracters:");
    System.out.println(" You need at least one digit:");
    System.out.println(" You need at least one special chracter:");
}
}
          if(password.length()>max||password.length()>=max&&upCount>1&&loCount>1&&digit>1){
     System.out.println(" Password is too long. The limit is "+max+" chracters:");
             System.out.println(" You need at least one special chracter:");

    }
  if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max&&loCount>0&&upCount>0&&digit>0&&special==0){
     System.out.println(" You need atleast a special chracter");
 }
  if(password.length()>=min&&password.length()<=max&&loCount>0&&upCount>0&&digit==0&&special==0){
     System.out.println(" You need at least one digit:");
     System.out.println(" You need at least one special chracter:");
 }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Should ask one question at a time. Also where is the Database save code? What error are you getting from the Database? What's happening when you try to block passwords with consecutive characters?

Comment: Use regular expressions for such things - also, please consider how you store passwords in a database - you should only strore salted hashes.

Comment: 1. 8-12 characters limit is pretty stupid, not to mention that 12 characters is not too safe nowadays. 2. No two same characters is the row would only piss me off as a user (when e.g. I have a whole sentence as a password and it contains word such as `moon`). You may want to check for things like `12345`, `abcde`, `qwerty` etc. instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead of having a count of all the special characters, uppercase, and lowercase, you could just have a `boolean` of each and if at the end all of them are true, you could insert the password into the database. For blocking passwords that have equal characters next to them, you could try something like this within the for loop.

```
if(i < (password.length() -1) && c == password.charAt( i+1 ) ) {
   //throw error message or set boolean of valid to false.
}
```

This says if i is less than length - 1 (so we can check the next index without array out of bounds exception), then check to see if the next char is equal to the current char.

Next, as some others have said, you should be storing passwords in a database as salted hashes. This is to make sure if your database is compromised, your passwords are hashed.